# How to animate a gun?

Tags: animation

How can i animate the reloding effect and the bullet shell effect like shell exploding out when firing do I have to make separate model of those shells and magazine?

Comment: Hi. Which specific part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am having trouble with those exploding shells I mean how can I animate them like when you fire the amount of shells are not only one but many do I have to add every other bone for every shell or there is another method please help